# Using HTML and CSS, is it possible to create the lines like below

Tags: html, css

I have very less knowledge of HTML and CSS. It was a success with creating the lines as a straight line. Not getting that how it can be modified the lines diagonally and straight. Not sure is it possible to create like below using coding. Appreciate your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRKtd.png)

Comment: it is possible. but you should probably have a look into svg as well

Answer (score 1):

A very rudimentary design, you could expand on it later...

```
.a {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    border-left: 6px solid green;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
<div class="a">
</div>
```

The line turn is made through the "transform" property.

-FruDe

Answer (score 0):

try transform property f.e. 
`transform: rotate(20deg);`
to rotate objects and get diagonally line

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score -1):

use transform you can learned about that in w3school